# Where the dotfiles gets instlled in GitHub Codespaces?

Tags: github, codespaces

I have a question about using a dotfiles repository with GitHub Codespaces. According to the official GitHub documentation, if I create a dotfiles repository and enable it in my settings, it should be automatically downloaded and the install script should be run whenever I create a new Codespaces project.

I have already configured my dotfiles repository and enabled it in my settings, but when I create a new Codespaces project, I am not able to see my dotfiles repository in the Codespace. I have checked all the files and folders that I can think of, but I can’t find it.

Can anyone tell me what the exact location of the dotfiles repository is in a Codespace? Is it possible to set the location of the repository in the devcontainer.json file?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is your dotfiles repository called?  As in, what's the URL?  Is it public or private?

Comment: https://github.com/thevedicdeveloper/dotfiles

Comment: the script is still in development state, probably it won't run at all for you, but I would if you help in finding where this will get clone.